# Scrape Multiple Pages with rvest from IMDB

Tags: r

So here I am trying to scrape data off of the IMDB link: https://www.imdb.com/search/title?release_date=2010-01-01,2017-12-31&count=100&start=101&ref_=adv_prv

And I want to scrape the runtime and title data with the code below. However, I am wondering how could I perform the same to multiple of the other pages? I tried doing a for loop but I don't know how to incorporate it into my code. The pattern is as follows:

```
https://www.imdb.com/search/title?release_date=2010-01-01,2017-12-31&count=100&start=101&ref_=adv_prv
https://www.imdb.com/search/title?release_date=2010-01-01,2017-12-31&count=100&start=201&ref_=adv_nxt
https://www.imdb.com/search/title?release_date=2010-01-01,2017-12-31&count=100&start=301&ref_=adv_nxt
```

My code:

```
url <- 'https://www.imdb.com/search/title?release_date=2010-01-01,2017-12-31&count=100&start=101&ref_=adv_prv'
    webpage <- read_html(url)

titlehtml <- html_nodes(webpage,'.lister-item-header a')
title <- html_text(titlehtml)


runtimehtml <- html_nodes(webpage,'.text-muted .runtime')
runtime <- html_text(runtimehtml)
runtime<-gsub(" min","",runtime)# removing mins and converting it to numerical
runtime<-as.numeric(runtime)
```

Comment: What did your for loop look like? How exactly didn't it work?

Comment: I tried something like this:

for(i in seq(101:901, by 100)) {
  url <- paste0("https://www.imdb.com/search/title?release_date=2010-01-01,2017-12-31&count=100&start=" i "&ref_=adv_prv")
  webpage[i] <- read_html(url)

  titlehtml <- html_nodes(webpage[i],'.lister-item-header a')
  title <- html_text(titlehtml)
  
  runtimehtml <- html_nodes(webpage[i],'.text-muted .runtime')
  runtime <- html_text(runtimehtml)
  runtime<-gsub(" min","",runtime)# removing mins and converting it to numerical
  runtime<-as.numeric(runtime)
  
  }

However it does not work

Comment: First, I would edit the code into your question so it can be properly formatted. But then what's the desired result here? What should exist when the loop is done running?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add I want to put it into a dataframe:

movies_df<-data.frame(Title = title,
                      Runtime = runtime)

Comment: Scraping IMDB is a violation of Amazon Terms & Conditions and IMDB also has a robust robots.txt. Anyone who helps you may be subject to the same IP ban, fines and/or penalties you are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
urls <- c("https://www.imdb.com/search/title?release_date=2010-01-01,2017-12-31&count=100&start=101&ref_=adv_prv",
      "https://www.imdb.com/search/title?release_date=2010-01-01,2017-12-31&count=100&start=201&ref_=adv_nxt",
      "https://www.imdb.com/search/title?release_date=2010-01-01,2017-12-31&count=100&start=301&ref_=adv_nxt")`

results_list <- list()

for(.page in seq_along(urls)){
  webpage <- read_html(urls[[.page]])
  titlehtml <- html_nodes(webpage,'.lister-item-header a')
  title <- html_text(titlehtml)
  runtimehtml <- html_nodes(webpage,'.text-muted .runtime')
  runtime <- html_text(runtimehtml)
  runtime <- gsub(" min","",runtime)
  results_list[[.page]] <- data.frame(title = title,
                                  runtime = as.numeric(runtime)
                                  )
}

final_results <- plyr::ldply(results_list)
```

Comment: Thank you this seems to work, one more question since I am new to R. How do i go about adding an extra column to results_list? Like if i want to scrape additional data thats not the runtime to store it in a new column.

Comment: You can add another column by placing a comma after `as.numeric(runtime)` and then writing something like `my_new_column = some_value`. Once you get the for loop doing everything you want it to, I would explore simplifying your code and using something like `lapply` or `purrr::map`. Those will usually end up being faster than a for loop, but a for loop is a great option to start with.

Comment: Thank you so much, now the last question is when I try to put in into a dataframe there are differing rows and therefore doesnt work. How would I go about making the empty values to be 'NA' instead?

Comment: I didn't run into the issue you mentioned in the example script. So, I'll need more information (example code) to help you there.

Comment: Please look at my post below: